# Scraped elements not showing up in .jl file

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

Quick background I'm learning to code with Python and at the same time learning to scrape. My problem here is that when I run this code, the console shows that indeed the wanted content is scraped, but when I open the .jl document it is empty. As I'm a beginner there might have been many things that I have missed. Thanks for your help and sorry in advance if I missed a similar post.

```
import scrapy

class ProgxSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'progx'
    allowed_domains = ['random.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.random.com.html']


    def parse(self, response):
         locations = []

        for i in response.selector.xpath('//div[@class="property-info- 
location ellipsis-element-control"]/text()').extract():
            locations.append(i)
        print(locations)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `yield` instead of just printing `locations` for the output to be present in .jl file

```
yield {'locations':locations}
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as the correct one, if it was helpful.